# Convert an theme options page to use in customize.php also?

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

I have developed a theme options page which is a submenu page of appearance. But now i like to know how what i need to do so the theme options are also editable in the theme->customize interface. (customize.php).

I tried a simple test by adding this to functions.php, to see if the customize menu is altered but no luck

```
//for customize.php
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
   //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
   //1. Define a new section (if desired) to the Theme Customizer
      $wp_customize->add_section( 'mytheme_options', 
         array(
            'title' => __( 'MyTheme Options', 'ppr' ), //Visible title of section
            'priority' => 35, //Determines what order this appears in
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Capability needed to tweak
            'description' => __('Allows you to customize some example settings for MyTheme.', 'ppr'), //Descriptive tooltip
         ) 
      );

      //2. Register new settings to the WP database...
      $wp_customize->add_setting( 'link_textcolor', //No need to use a SERIALIZED name, as `theme_mod` settings already live under one db record
         array(
            'default' => '#2BA6CB', //Default setting/value to save
            'type' => 'theme_mod', //Is this an 'option' or a 'theme_mod'?
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', //Optional. Special permissions for accessing this setting.
            'transport' => 'postMessage', //What triggers a refresh of the setting? 'refresh' or 'postMessage' (instant)?
         ) 
      );      

    //
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
//end cutomize.php
```

regards,

Comment: Whats not working? Is it adding any fields to the customizer or is nothing working?

Comment: @willow, well in my case it isn't working i don't see the section My theme options. ![link](http://bldd.nl/problems/customize.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a control to it.

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

  $wp_customize->add_section( 'mytheme_options', 
     array(
        'title' => __( 'MyTheme Options', 'ppr' ),
        'priority' => 35,
        'description' => __('Allows you to customize some example settings for MyTheme.', 'ppr'),
     ) 
  );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'link_textcolor', array(
    'default' => get_option( 'your_theme_page_option_value' ), THIS IS THE OPTION NAME YOU CREATED WITH YOUR OPTIONS PAGE CODE
    'type' => 'option',  // FOR OPTIONS USE OPTION
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'transport' => 'refresh', // WILL REFRESH INSTEAD OF JS. YOU HAVE TO WRITE JS TO MAKE UPDATE INSTANT... ITS A PAIN IN THE ASS http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_preview_init
) );


// THIS IS WHAT YOU WERE MISSING
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
    'label'        => __( 'Link Text Color', 'ppr' ),
    'section'    => 'mytheme_options', // ID OF SECTION ABOVE
    'settings'   => 'link_textcolor', // ID OF SETTINGS ABOVE
) ) );

}
 add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

Alex make sure you are including the options in your templates otherwise you wont see any changes. For example if you want to us the options in all templates make sure you are actually putting the option inside the header or all the files that will need changes.

So for the above code I would use something like this and place it in my header.php or even just in a function that uses the `wp_head` action if it's for styles.

```
function mytheme_customizer_styles() {
        $link_text_color = get_option('your_theme_page_option_value'); // THIS IS THE OPTION VALUE THAT YOU CREATED WITH SETTINGS API AND YOUR CUSTOM OPTIONS PAGE AND IS ALSO THE NAME OF THE OPTIONS DEFINED IN THE `add_setting` field above.
    ?>
    <style type="text/css" id="mytheme-customizer-admin-header-css">
         .link-text-color { color:  <?php echo $link_text_color; ?>; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_customizer_styles', 9999); // JUST MAKE SURE THE PRIORITY IS LATE ENOUGH SO ITS NOT OVERRIDEEN
```

Comment: Just code is a bad answer. Please, explain what the code does and why it answers the question.

Comment: I still recommend using styles Plugin. All this code is complete waste of time!

Comment: that is your opinion. I prefer code my own, especially if you are going to add only a few customization options there is no reason to install a heavier plugin. Also, that plugin only support a very few themes, so it is not a solution at all from a developer point of view.

Comment: tx willow, i indeed was missing a control. As i said i have already created an options page which works ok. To make my theme a bit user friendly i like the options also be accesible through the optimize.php

Comment: hi guys, how do i save the option values. Because now it always saves the default values i have set.

Comment: Were you able to get the options to save? I updated my answer.

Comment: @willow i checked and updated with  `'default' => get_option('theme_ppr_options'),` but still the options are not saved. My options page does trigger a function on admin_init `function ppr_options_settings_init() {
    register_setting( 'theme_ppr_options', 'theme_ppr_options', 'ppr_options_validate' );......` and ppr_options_validate has `function ppr_options_validate( $input ) {
    $default_options = ppr_get_default_options();
    $valid_input = $default_options;` maybe this part is always being triggered and ppr_get_default_options() is executed?

Comment: 2nd question i use WP_Customize_Image_Control for one control but it doesn't let me select an already uploaded image?

Comment: btw: i also tried ` $ppr_options = get_option( 'theme_ppr_options' ); 'default' =>  $ppr_options['rating']` for my rating option still not being saved

Comment: @willow still not working the way i want it. It only works if i enable one or the other. So the options panel or by customize. Somehow i must bypass the function which saves the options from the panel, when i am in customize